# python numpy or scipy error

Tags: python, anaconda, numpy

I want to work in python. When I import scipy or numpy it shows these errors:

```
saikat@saikat:~/Downloads/Python-2.7.15$ python
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>>
```

But when I use this commands:

```
sudo pip install numpy scipy
```

It shows:

```
saikat@saikat:~/Downloads/Python-2.7.15$ sudo pip install numpy scipy
The directory '/home/saikat/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/saikat/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.14.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.1.0).
```

What should I do?

Comment: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Anaconda Python and not system Python version. Because you use Anaconda, your package should be installed using `conda` or Anaconda `pip` version. Using `base` environment of the default Anaconda installation, Numpy and Scipy are already installed, if not:

```
conda install numpy scipy
```